# Linspace with automatic number of points

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

When using `np.linspace` like this:

```
x[a:int(b*2.2+5)] = np.linspace(234.0, 23.4, ...
```

one has to:

- either repeat the array slice:

  ```
  x[a:int(b*2.2+5)] = np.linspace(234.0, 23.4, len(x[a:int(b*2.2+5)]))
  ```
- or compute its length:

  ```
  x[a:int(b*2.2+5)] = np.linspace(234.0, 23.4, int(b*2.2+5)-a)
  ```
- or use another variable:

  ```
  r = range(a,int(b*2.2+5))
  x[r] = np.linspace(234.0, 23.4, len(r))
  ```
- <strike>or create a slice:</strike>

  ```
  x2 = x[a:int(b*2.2+5)]
  x2 = np.linspace(234.0, 23.4, len(x2))
  ```

  (The latter would not work because it would not modify `x`, as requested)

**Is there a shorter way that would automatically infer the length?** like this:

```
x[a:int(b*2.2+5)] = np.autolinspace(234.0, 23.4)
```

Or is there a built-in Numpy function:

```
linspace(234.0, 23.4, destination_array=x[a:int(b*2.2+5)])
```

Comment: The version I'd use would be `new_values = np.linspace(234.0, 23.4, int(b*2.2+5)-a)` followed by `x[a:a+len(new_values)] = new_values`. This way, the first one is array creation and has nothing to do with `x`. The second is assignment. Easy to read and easy to modify when you decide some time later that linspace should be something else. Some NumPy methods do have an `out` argument, but it always requires an array of exact size: there is no "assign whatever slice fits" in NumPy.

Comment: Don't try to be cheap.  No one is charging you for characters.  Choose the clearest approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think because of the lvalue vs rvalue rule, since the rvalue is evaluated first, it is not possible to automatically infer the length like what you ask for.

One way would be if you write a custom wrapper over numpy arrays and override `__setitem__` correctly. But that's too much trouble than a convenience to me.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on your last rejected solution does work

```
In [180]: x=np.zeros(20)
In [181]: x2=x[2:10]
In [182]: x2[:] = np.linspace(0,1,len(x2))
In [183]: x
Out[183]: 
array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.14285714, 0.28571429,
       0.42857143, 0.57142857, 0.71428571, 0.85714286, 1.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ])
```

`x2` is a `view`, so modifying it does modify `x`.

The cleanest solution I can think of is to start with a `slice` object:

```
In [188]: idx = slice(2,10)
In [189]: x[idx] = np.linspace(1,2,idx.stop-idx.start)
In [190]: x
Out[190]: 
array([0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 1.14285714, 1.28571429,
       1.42857143, 1.57142857, 1.71428571, 1.85714286, 2.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ])
```

Comment: You want modify `x2`, not assign a new value.